# How to view a method code from exe file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exe

I have a project in VB .NET Windows Forms. There I try to use some functions from an exe file. This exe file I think is also VB .NET projekt but sure is Windows Forms. Some functions works but a function don't work. I tried to open this file with .NET Refelector from Red Gate software but I see something like that:

```
Try 
    Dim num2 As Integer
Label_0000:
    Dim num4 As Integer = 1
Label_0008:
...
```

When I open C# project exe file I see all function very good.

```
int num = 0;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
builder.Append("DELETE FROM Users ");
builder.Append("WHERE User_ID = @id ");
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(builder.ToString(), this.con);
```

How (with whom) I can open this exe file (VB.NET Project) to view function code?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be obfuscated

Comment: As Alireza said, the multiple labels suggest that some form of control flow obfuscation is used. That means the code was changed by a program after compilation to jump around wildly while still maintaining its original functionality to annoy potential reverse engineers that have no business to look at the code (aka: you). Depending on how extensively that is done you have to invest a lot of time to find out what the function does. But nobody here will (and can) really help you I guess, since it seems like a legal gray area to put it mildly.

Comment: Contact the developer of the application, if he wants to help you out...